# Why does screen width and screen change with changing orientation?

Tags: android, height, width, screen, screen-size

I ran an application on my nexus 7 that calculated the screen width and height on my device. In portrait mode, my application gave me a height of 1824 px and a width of 1200 px. These dimensions made sense to me. However in landscape mode, my application gave me a height of 1104px and a width of 1920 px. From [Does the Width and Height change with orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699297/does-the-width-and-height-change-with-orientation), I got that with changing orientation, screen width and height change, but shouldnt the dimensions just flip?  To me, its the same fundamental screen

The code i used to calculate the screen size

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int height = display.getHeight();
int width = display.getWidth();
```

Comment: maybe that difference is because of the notification bar on the top which is changing as well if you flip the device?

Comment: yeah but if you count the notification bar, it still takes up the same width /height