# Android Screen Recording How-To - Landscape recording, video recorded plays in full-screen vs partial-screen

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder, screen-recording, android-mediaprojection

I am currently using Media Projection + Media Recorder to do screen recording. The problem I am facing is, when my phone is in Landscape mode during recording, the video recorded will only be shown in the center/middle of the screen with black on top and below it during playback ([what it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZl79.png), [what I would like instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiW5U.png)).

I do see apps out there (such as AirShou) that can record in Landscape and the videos they record are full-screen during playback. What do I need to do for that to happen?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your question, you didn't add any problem image. I tried to understand your problem on my way. As i don't have permission to comment yet so just trying to describe the solution with guessing your video is recorded and played fine:
1. During Landscape mode your display width and height changes see this [Does the Width and Height change with orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699297/does-the-width-and-height-change-with-orientation)

You can re-code by resetting the value of recording screen during screen orientation to Landscape mode. And add a new different layout for orientation to Landscape mood. 
you can see this

```
            DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
        int screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
        int screenDensity = metrics.densityDpi;

        // Start the video input.
        mVirtualDisplay = mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("Recording Display", screenWidth,
                screenHeight, screenDensity, 0 /* flags */, mInputSurface,
                null /* callback */, null /* handler */);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Adjusting/Swapping the width and height helps me achieve what I need to achieve.

Comment: So many thanks, This is what @Cookies 'n Creme want to ask in the question. Your answer's 100% working.

Answer (score 1):

If any one is still looking for answer - in addition to what @md-sulayman suggested, make sure you also swap the width height in

```
mediaRecorder.setVideoSize
```

like this -

```
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT); // for portrait
```

and

```
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(HEIGHT,WIDTH); // for landscape
```

Comment: we can't change the video size during recording since the documentation states:-
"throws IllegalStateException if it is called after
 prepare() or before setOutputFormat()"